# How to pass the values to the other html page and redirect the to that page for onclick thumbnail using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, jquery-ui

Here I need to click on a thumbnail, so that it will show the details on other page, it should show the details of that particular thumb only. I used xml file here to fetch the data and display thumbnail. I am unable to pass the values to other page and open it at the same time onclick event. pls help

```
<div class="container-page">

            <div class="row" id="portfolio">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="test">
                            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#portfolio" id="services">Services</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#portfolio" id="desktop">Desktop</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#portfolio" id="web">Web</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#portfolio" id="mobile">Mobile</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#portfolio" id="design">Design</a></li>
                        </ul>   
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="row" id="thumb">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<!-- js -->
$.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"portfolio.xml",
            dataType:"xml",
            success:function(xml)
            {

                $(xml).find('thumbnail').each(function()
                {
                    var $thumbnail=$(this);

                                            var type=$thumbnail.find('type').text();
                                            var descr=$thumbnail.find('description').text();
                                            var title=$thumbnail.attr('title');
                    var imageurl=$thumbnail.attr('imageurl');
                    var thum='<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"> </div>';
                                            thum=$(thum).appendTo("#thumb");
                    thum = $('<a href="#" class="thumbnail forHove"></a>').appendTo(thum);
                    var thumName = $('<div class="thumTitle"></div>').appendTo(thum);
                    $('<h2>'+title+'</h2>').appendTo(thumName);
                    $('<p>'+type+'</p>').appendTo(thumName)
                    thum = $('<img src="'+imageurl+'" alt="image" class="thumbImgSize imgSlide">').appendTo(thum);
                    $(".forHove").mouseup(function()
                    {
     //here is the redirection code, and want to pass $thumbnail to  testxml.html page
window.location="http://www.bookmane.in/skillworks/testxml.html";
                $(thum).appendTo(".s");
        });
                });
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, one of the alternative is using [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).
Just store img html and use it.

```js
// use 'click' instead of 'mouseup'
$(".forHove").click(function()
{
  // store image html to sessionStorage
  window.sessionStorage.image_data = $thumbnail.clone().wrapAll("<div>").parent().html();
  
  window.location="http://www.bookmane.in/skillworks/testxml.html";
  $(thum).appendTo(".s");
});


// in http://www.bookmane.in/skillworks/testxml.html
// You have data sotred and insert it somewhere
$(document.body).append(window.sessionStorage.image_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this thing using the following steps:

1. Add a form tag like

   ```html
   <form action="YOUR_PATH" method="GET">
       <a class="thubnailClick" href="#" >
           <html_of_your_thumbnail>
           <input type="text" name="NAME_OF_PARAMETER" />
     </a>
   </form>
   ```
2. Now override the click event of `<a>` tag with

   ```javascript
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".thubnailClick").on('click', function(event) {
           // to override the default behavior of <a> tag. 
           preventDefault();          
           // Find the form element using closest() of jQuery.
           // Call submit event of that form using $(form_element).submit();
       });
   })
   ```
3. Now on the other page you can get parameter from URL using location.search or follow:
   [Getting Query params using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter)
4. Now use these Params according to your needs.